# OnDataBound not fired for asp:DropDownList with static asp:ListItems

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, drop-down-menu, listitem

I have an `<asp:DropDownList>` witch gets filled by static list items.

```
<asp:DropDownList ... OnDataBound="handlerMethod">
    <asp:ListItem Value="..." Text="..." />
    <asp:ListItem Value="..." Text="..." />
    <asp:ListItem Value="..." Text="..." />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The problem is that the `OnDataBound` event does not get triggered when the list is filled. I need it to trigger to fill some other data from the list items that are in the dropdown.

The documentation says:

> This method notifies a server control that any data binding logic associated with the control has completed.

My eyes are on this "logic" word which makes me thing that i missed the point on when the event is triggered

But if that is the case, how can I get the event triggered or what other event can I use to know when the list has finished beeing filled?

Comment: Did you say static? You type them in `.aspx` file? If so, it won't be triggered. I think it will be triggered when you use the `.Bind` method.

Comment: @domanokz: Yes, I type them in .aspx.

Answer (score 2):

Normally this means that you have deleted the `AutoEventWireup="true"` or set it to false, and that's why it's not wiring up the event.

**It can also mean** that there is something wrong in the javascript that does not allow anymore code to run. Open the inspector (Chrome, Safari or Firebug in Firefox - Do not rely on IE Developer tools) and see if you have any javascript errors that can cause the page to stop.

**It can also mean** that the `handlerMethod` is not correctly set up, best way is to delete the html part `OnDataBound="handlerMethod"` and the code behind of this method, then go to `design view`, open the Properties window in the Events and double click the `OnDataBound`, it will add the event correctly. Set up a break point there and run in debug with `debug="true"` in your `web.config` file.

Comment: the handlerMethod is correctly set up; I checked that. I don't really understand your first point. What does JavaScript have to do with this?

Comment: it will never let you do a post!