# strange behaviour of asplistbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

first I checked every word here :

Click [questions/6621510](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621510/ondatabound-not-fired-for-aspdropdownlist-with-static-asplistitems)

My problem description:
I have the next design :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnltmpTermCats" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
<ContentTemplate>
<div class="alt">
<div class="msgnoteborder">

<div class="panelistbox">
<asp:ListBox ID="lsttmpTermCats" runat="server" DataValueField="ProposalTermCatID" DataTextField="TermCatName"  
Rows="10" SelectionMode="Single"  AutoPostBack="true"    OnSelectedIndexChanged="lsttmpTermCats_SelectedIndexChanged" />
</div>

<div class="panelistbox">
<asp:ListBox ID="lstTermSubCat" runat="server" DataValueField="ProposalTermSubCatID" DataTextField="TermVirtualName"  
Rows="10"  SelectionMode="Single"  OnDataBinding="lstTermSubCat_DataBinding" OnDataBound="lstTermSubCat_DataBound" ViewStateMode="Enabled"  />
<div class="layoutbuttons">
<asp:ImageButton ID="TermSubCatUpBtn" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Data/SiteImages/up.gif"
CommandName="up" 
CommandArgument="TermSubCat"
SkinID="pageLayoutMoveUp" CssClass="btnup" />

<asp:ImageButton ID="TermSubCatDownBtn" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Data/SiteImages/dn.gif"
CommandName="down" 
CommandArgument="TermSubCat"
SkinID="pageLayoutMoveDown"
CssClass="btndown" />
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div> 
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

With code behind :

```
    protected void lstTermSubCat_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            int indx = -1;
            indx = lstTermSubCat.SelectedIndex;
            string txt = string.Empty;
            txt = lstTermSubCat.Items[indx].Text;
            lstTermSubCat.Items[indx].Text = Regex.Replace((txt).ToString(), @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty).Replace("\r\n", String.Empty).Trim();

    }

    protected void lstTermSubCat_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // ListItem item = lstTermSubCat.Items. .Item;
        int indx = -1;
        indx = lstTermSubCat.SelectedIndex;
        string txt = string.Empty;
        txt = lstTermSubCat.Items[indx].Text;
        lstTermSubCat.Items[indx].Text = Regex.Replace((txt).ToString(), @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty).Replace("\r\n", String.Empty).Trim();

    }
```

If i put OnSelectedIndexChanged in the second listbox it will works but other events are not firing !

ok, 
it is rely strange!
i made new page 
simple one :
the design is :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="testlist.aspx.cs" Inherits="UHSRFP.Features.UI.Admin.UHSRFP.Proposal.testlist" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnltmpTermCats" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:ListBox ID="lsttmpTermCats" runat="server" 
DataValueField="ProposalTermCatID" DataTextField="TermCatName"  
Rows="10" SelectionMode="Single"  AutoPostBack="true"   
OnSelectedIndexChanged="lsttmpTermCats_SelectedIndexChanged"
OnDataBinding="lsttmpTermCats_DataBinding"
OnDataBound="lsttmpTermCats_DataBound" />

<asp:ListBox ID="lstTermSubCat" runat="server" 
DataValueField="ProposalTermSubCatID" DataTextField="TermVirtualName"   
Rows="10" SelectionMode="Single"  AutoPostBack="true"    
OnSelectedIndexChanged="lsttmpTermCats_SelectedIndexChanged"
OnDataBinding="lstTermSubCat_DataBinding" 
OnDataBound="lstTermSubCat_DataBound"
/>

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>     
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the code behind is :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using UHSRFP.Business;
using UHSRFP.Features.UI.Helper;
using mojoPortal.Business;
using mojoPortal.Business.WebHelpers;
using mojoPortal.Web.Framework;
using mojoPortal.Web;
using mojoPortal.Web.AdminUI;
using mojoPortal.Web.Editor;
using mojoPortal.Web.UI;
using Resources;

namespace UHSRFP.Features.UI.Admin.UHSRFP.Proposal
{
    public partial class testlist : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private int proposalID = 11;
        private int siteid = 1;
        int termCatID = -1;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {




            PopulateControls();




        }



        private void PopulateControls()
        {

            if ((this.proposalID > 0) & (!Page.IsPostBack))
            {

                Bind_tmpTermCatList();
                //Bind_TermSubCatList();

            }

        }

        private void Bind_tmpTermCatList()
        {
            lsttmpTermCats.Items.Clear();
            ArrayList proposalTermCategories = ProposalTermCategory.GetArrayProposalTermCats(this.siteid, this.proposalID);

            foreach (ProposalTermCategory proposalTermCategory in proposalTermCategories)
            {
                ListItem listItem = new ListItem(proposalTermCategory.TermCat.Coalesce(Resource.ContentNoTitle), proposalTermCategory.ProposalTermCatID.ToInvariantString());
                lsttmpTermCats.Items.Add(listItem);
            }

            if (this.lsttmpTermCats.Items.Count > 0)
                this.lsttmpTermCats.SelectedIndex = 0;

            this.termCatID = int.Parse(lsttmpTermCats.SelectedValue);

            ListItem item = lsttmpTermCats.Items.FindByValue(this.termCatID.ToInvariantString());
            if (item != null)
            {
                lsttmpTermCats.ClearSelection();
                item.Selected = true;
            }

            Bind_TermSubCatList();
        }

        private void Bind_TermSubCatList()
        {
            lstTermSubCat.Items.Clear();
            ArrayList proposalTermSubCategories = ProposalTermSubCategory.GetArrayProposalTermSubCats(this.siteid, this.termCatID);

            foreach (ProposalTermSubCategory proposalTermSubCategory in proposalTermSubCategories)
            {
                ListItem listItem = new ListItem(proposalTermSubCategory.TermSubCatDescr.Coalesce(Resource.ContentNoTitle), proposalTermSubCategory.ProposalTermSubCatID.ToInvariantString());
                lstTermSubCat.Items.Add(listItem);
            }
        }

        protected void lstTermSubCat_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // ListItem item = lstTermSubCat.Items. .Item;
            int indx = -1;
            indx = lstTermSubCat.SelectedIndex;
            string txt = string.Empty;
            txt = lstTermSubCat.Items[indx].Text;
            lstTermSubCat.Items[indx].Text = Regex.Replace((txt).ToString(), @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty).Replace("\r\n", String.Empty).Trim();

        }

        protected void lstTermSubCat_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // ListItem item = lstTermSubCat.Items. .Item;
            int indx = -1;
            indx = lstTermSubCat.SelectedIndex;
            string txt = string.Empty;
            txt = lstTermSubCat.Items[indx].Text;
            lstTermSubCat.Items[indx].Text = Regex.Replace((txt).ToString(), @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty).Replace("\r\n", String.Empty).Trim();

        }

        protected void lsttmpTermCats_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.termCatID = int.Parse(lsttmpTermCats.SelectedValue);
            Bind_TermSubCatList();
        }

        protected void lsttmpTermCats_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.termCatID = int.Parse(lsttmpTermCats.SelectedValue);
            //Bind_TermSubCatList();
        }

        protected void lsttmpTermCats_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.termCatID = int.Parse(lsttmpTermCats.SelectedValue);
        }

    }
}
```

and still not working
the problem is that ONLY the events OnDataBinding and OnDataBound are not firing while on index change still working well !!
is there any tip here please ?

any help here will be as gift cause i spent long time trying every thing without results !!!
thanks

Comment: I mean events : OnDataBinding and OnDataBound are not firing wile OnSelectedIndexChanged is firing !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember if your controls don't have the bound data-source when the page is fully rendered they won't fire neither DataBinding nor DataBound events for you.

So you must bind the data-source either on their control properties (.aspx file) or on your Page_load event before the control fire the DataBiniding or DataBound event.

therefore you need to use `DataBind()` method after you set the data to your controls.

```
    private void Bind_tmpTermCatList()
    {
        //your datasource code here

        lsttmpTermCats.DataBind(); //bind your control here
        Bind_TermSubCatList();
    }
```

and in your sub list you will have something like this:

```
    private void Bind_TermSubCatList()
    {
        // your datasource code here...
        lstTermSubCat.DataBind();  //bind your sub control here
    }
```

now you will see two events `lsttmpTermCats_DataBinding` and `lsttmpTermCats_DataBound` will fire afterwards.

Cheers